# Data cleaning in Python for pdf scraping

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and need help with data cleaning.

The objective is to scrape tables from pdf file. That has been done with the tabula package and I have a CSV file.

In the original PDF file, the description can be long (up to 3 -4 lines) as shown in the picture below.
[img][https://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y190/fongwee1/PDF_table.jpg[/img]](https://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y190/fongwee1/PDF_table.jpg%5B/img%5D)

After scraping, this is what I get in my DataFrame.
[img][https://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y190/fongwee1/Data_frame.jpg[/img]](https://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y190/fongwee1/Data_frame.jpg%5B/img%5D)

I need to combine the rows for the same description together.
Example: I need to combine index 4 and 5 together so that it would read as the following:
Index    S/N     Code                     Description                                                                  Table
4         5      Description Change       Breast, Lumps, Imaging Guided Vacuum Assisted Biopsy, Single lesion          2B

It should also delete Index 5 row after combing it together. Finally, I need to set a find and replace function to do it to the whole dataframe.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without your scraping source code, it is hard to provide a specific solution.

At a high level, it seems that, after scraping, you could loop through each row. If the entry for S/N is `nan`, then combine the values for each row.

You could even do this as you scrape, where as you scrape each row, you check if you'd get `nan` for the S/N. If so, then append the values for each column to the existing values. Otherwise, start a new entry. This would address your point "It should also delete Index 5 row after combing it together." because that empty row would never actually get created.